0 static files copied to 'C:\Users\Reynald\Desktop\Test\cdo_portal\staticfiles', 2365 unmodified
Hello everyone might someone here know how to fix this
i just trying to run manage.py collectstatic but when i run the sytsem all of the design was a mess and when i check the collecstatic

0 static files copied to 'C:\Users\Reynald\Desktop\Test\cdo_portal\staticfiles', 2365 unmodified.

not sure of that
settings.py
STATIC_URL = '/static/' 
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles') 
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') ]

I already tried another way to fix this but still not working

2365 unmodified this means all needed files are already in the target folder. I guess you get 404 on every static file url, so show your project folder structure mostly related to static files, urls.py, example of static file reference in a template, elaborate if DEBUG=true or false and show example of static file URL and the specific error message (http status) code.
